# Consequence of having a polynomial time randomised algorithm for graph colouring, which shows Yes and No with probability $1$ and $p(n) \sim_{n} 1$

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, complexity-theory

Suppose we have a randomized algorithm that takes a graph G and color k as inputs and provides yes if the graph is k-colorable and no with probability $p(n)$ if it's not k-colorable, where $n$ is the number of vertices. What is the consequence if someone comes with a proof that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p(n) = 1$.

Does it imply that graph coloring in BPP or ZPP?

Comment: This question should be asked on [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Olivier is there any way to transfer this question there?

Comment: Not that I know.